# Запятая после "однако"

Tags: пунктуация

Попалась Чеховская фраза: "Однако, какой ветер!" После "однако" стояла запятая. Но ведь это слово в начале предложения запятой не выделяется. Или бывают исключения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это междометие, выражающее сильное чувство (удивление, возмущение). Междометие может находиться в начале или в конце предложения, выделяется запятой, а также восклицательным знаком: Тридцать тысяч, однако! Однако! Тридцать тысяч!

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
В начале предложения ОДНАКО имеет значение союза НО и не обособляется: Однако ужин задержался... Вводное слово ОДНАКО со значением противопоставления ранее сказанному ставится в середину предложения: Надо, однако, сказать несколько слов... Но, однако, я попросил бы вас перейти к делу.

Answer (score 2):

"Однако" здесь - вводное слово, обозначающее эмоциональное отношение говорящего к происходящему, поэтому тут ставится запятая. Где бы ни стояло вводное слово, в середине или в начале предложения, либо, возможно, в его конце, оно всегда выделяется запятыми (или одной запятой).

Comment: Павел, междометия и вводные слова, действительно, всегда обособляются, но при этом имеют разные области значения: междометия обозначают чувства, НЕ НАЗЫВАЯ их конкретно, а вводные слова выражают различные модальные отношения (в том числе и эмоции) или служат для оформления речи. "ОДНАКО" в качестве вводного слова служит для противопоставления ранее сказанного тому, что говорится в данный момент. Эмоциональное отношение это слово не выражает. Сравнить: Ветер, однако, всё усиливался (а мы думали, что он утихнет). - Ветер, к сожалению, всё усиливался. Это вводные слова с разным значением.

Comment: София, с запятой – это только вводное слово. Да, вместе с тем, которое обозначает противопоставление («Я, однако, с вами не согласен»). Поверьте на слово (а хотите - проверьте), что вводные слова иногда обозначают эмоциональное отношение (оценку) говорящего к происходящему. Междометие – лишь с восклицательным знаком - для обозначения восклицательной  интонации, удивления, недоумения, возмущения и т.п.: «Его недавно брали в академики. - Однако!», «Я непременно стану великой певицей. - Однако!» Да, тут похоже на междометие, и всё же – не междометие, а, грамматически, вводное слово.

Comment: Это тонкость, которую не все знают. Но вот что говорят учёные. «Слова, синтаксически не связанные с предложением и выражающие отношение говорящего к сообщению, общую оценку сообщения, указание на источник сообщения или на его связь с контекстом речи... В. с. могут содержать эмоциональную оценку сообщения («к счастью», «к сожалению») или призыв к вниманию (...), указывать на степень достоверности («правда», «видимо»), источник («говорят», «известно»), стиль («попросту») или на отношение между частями сообщения («кстати», «наконец»).          В. В. Раскин.

Comment: Ещё несколько примеров из классики и словарей для осмысления темы. В. И. Даль: «Поскрючило его однако бедняка, подвело живот». «Однако, позапекся ты на солнце. Кровь позапеклась, немного» (он же). Однако, собака повизгивает что-то, не отдавили ль ей лапу? Ну, повизжит, да и перестанет. С лаю и повизгу выжлоков лес застонал. Мда, какой симпатишный балашка, однако. И какая стильная рубашка у красавца (киргизский сайт). Ипполит смотрел то на него, то на тетю Лучицкую и думал о Вареньке: - Однако, среди каких монстров она живет! (Горький).

Comment: Скажите, однако ж... - продолжал он [Чичиков], обратившись тут же с некоторым видом изумления к Маниловым, - в такие лета и уже такие сведения! (Гоголь). «Однако ж, Хавронья Никифоровна, сердце мое жаждет от вас кушанья послаще всех пампушечек и галушечек.» Гоголь. «Сканируют возможную террористку: подозрительно смуглая (загар, однако!)…» UrbanDictionary (Ru-Ru). Какой вы, однако, тюлень, Володя! Вы всё сидите, молчите». Чехов.

Comment: Павел, спасибо за ваши примеры, я с удовольствием их прочитала. Тем не менее, слово ОДНАКО в этих предложениях мне по-прежнему хочется считать междометиями. Вводные слова и междометия имеют область, где их значения пересекаются, - это  чувства (отношение)  автора к происходящим событиям. И здесь различие в том, что вводные слова называют конкретные чувства, а междометие ОДНАКО выражает эти чувства, не называя их,  - читатель  сам должен определить их.
В ваших примерах это озабоченность, приятное и неприятное удивление, досада - и всё это удивительным образом выражает одно и то же слово.